# Make web form that outputs multiple pdf among other things

Tags: database, forms, pdf, web

I'm writing contracts by hand along with itineraries that contain much of the same data. Is there a way to do the following...

1. web form that will fill the fields of my contract and outputs in .pdf format
2. button that gives the option to also output the data in the form of my itinerary layout in .pdf
3. save various details to a database.

what tutorials might be useful to me? what videos should i be watching to steer me down the right path?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like an application for a server-side form filling tool. The tool of choice would be FDFMerge by Appligent.

A typical workflow would be as follows:

• you have a web form where the user fills in the required information

• user submits the web form to your server where the data gets filled into a database

• selects are made in the database, bringing together the data for a specific document

• assemble the result of the selects into an FDF file

• the base form is filled with the data, using the above mentioned tool

• the filled document(s) is/are made available for the user

And that should do it.